# for each loop exit when result is found

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

I've got this code below. Let's say I've got 3 users in my list.
userNo1
userNo2
userNo3
I want to pass username and password in the console so the method that contains this loop checks if data is correct.
**My problem is:**i want to log into account number3, but the console prints "ERROR" 2 times and then finally "OK" (i know why but - it checks this condidion for every object in a list but i cannot come up with solution for that)
How to change this code so it only writes "OK" when login/pass is correct and prints only once "ERROR" if passed data is wrong?

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5iDw.png)

```
            System.out.print("Login: ");
            String username = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Password: ");
            String password = scanner.nextLine();

            for(User checkedUser : userList) {
                if ((username.equals(checkedUser.getUsername())) &&
                        (password.equals(checkedUser.getPassword()))) {
                    System.out.println("OK");


                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Post all code here directly as text.

Comment: You're iterating through the list of users everytime you attempt to log on, i'm guessing you get 2x "ERROR" and "OK" because you're logging on with the UserNo3. Use a hashmap instead of a List to store your user credentials. Having said that, probably not very secure.

Answer (score 0):

add `break;` statement after your conditions are met to exit the loop.

like

```
 boolean isAuthorized = false;
 for(User checkedUser : userList) {
     if ((username.equals(checkedUser.getUsername())) &&
         (password.equals(checkedUser.getPassword()))) {
             System.out.println("OK");
             isAuthorized = true;
             break;
     }
 }

 if(!isAuthorized){
     System.out.println("ERROR"); // auth failed
 }
```

The `break;` statement exit the loop immediately

Comment: This will still print "ERROR" twice, then print "OK" then break when checking UserNo3.

Comment: it still writes "error" 2 times when i try to log into account number 3. like it still checks that condition for every object until the right one is found :(

Comment: try out this one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok In Java 8 You can use Streams. Filter any user that is equal and password. return a boolean result.

```
userList.stream()                       
                .filter(x -> username .equals(x.getUsername()) && password.equals(x.getPassword()))        
                .findAny().isPresent();

        if(exist)
        {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
```

And if you are using Java version < 8. Iterate all the list if found break it and return true. Else the auxiliar variable will be false.

```
boolean exist = false;
        for(User checkedUser : userList) {
            if ((username.equals(checkedUser.getUsername())) &&
                    (password.equals(checkedUser.getPassword()))) {
                exist = true;
                break;
            } 
        }

        if(exist)
        {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your Username and Passwords as key/value pairs in a hashmap. Then check if `map.containsKey(username)`, if true check if `password.equals(map.getValue(username)))`

Effecitvely you can get the above done in a single line of code

```
System.out.println(map.containsKey(username) && password.equals(map.getValue(username)) ? "OK" : "ERROR");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to only print "ERROR" once if the login was unsuccessful, you have to move the print statement outside of the loop. As long as the print statement is inside of the loop, you will end up with multiple prints.

In order to do this, you will need to also have a variable declared prior to the loop that will house the result of the validation going on within the loop:

```
String result = "ERROR"
for(User checkedUser : userList) {
        if ((username.equals(checkedUser.getUsername())) &&
                (password.equals(checkedUser.getPassword()))) {
            result == "OK";
            break;
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

"ERROR" is being printed multiple times because every mismatch in the list of User objects results in "ERROR" being printed. This can be avoided by removing the else statement and inserting another if statement OUTSIDE the loop:

```
        System.out.print("Login: ");
        String username = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean status = false;

        for(User checkedUser : userList) {
            if ((username.equals(checkedUser.getUsername())) &&
                    (password.equals(checkedUser.getPassword()))) {
                System.out.println("OK");
                status = true;
            } 
        }

        if(status == false)
                  System.out.println("ERROR");
```